# WYSIWYG editor without actually using html input?

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg, text-editor

I'm making a forum-like website, and really want to implement a WYSIWYG editor if possible because my targeted users are foreign to technical work. Doing something like image upload/display/resize using markups will be too hard for them I suppose.

But after reading here on stackoverflow and trying it out myself, I suppose the WYSIWYG editor I'm using (WYSIHTML5) won't be safe enough for public use.

So come my questions:

1. Is there any "WYSIWYG editor"-like library that doesn't actually use html markup? Something like stackoverflow's editor (with toolbar and a real time preview box) is acceptable actually.
2. If there's nothing like that, is there anyway you can think of to implement WYSIWYG editor that can prevent user from doing harm to the server and/or other users? What can I do to ensure that?

Comment: Why not use bbcode like 90% of forums?

Comment: Because it's totally not WYSIWYG I think? I haven't seen any forum with a real time preview box.

Comment: I've used markitup before for html I believe it has a bbcode editor as well you can try

Comment: i dont like so editor it's weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like StackOverflow's editor and think it will fit your needs, it's [called PageDown.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121981/stackoverflow-official-wmd-editor) You can find the code [here.](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/)